# Конвертация string в int. C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a={"1","2"};
    int b, c;
    int atoi(const char *str);
    b=atoi(a[0].c_str());
    c=atoi(a[1].c_str());
    cout<<b+c;

    return 0;
}
```

Создаю массив типа string "a", там находится два числа, хочу эти числа превратить в числа типа int, чтобы потом их сложить, но не получается(

Comment: Вмсето `string a={"1","2"};` добавьте `string a[]={"1","2"};`

Comment: 1) Объявите переменную `a` как массив: `string a[2] = {"1", "2"};` 2) Удалите строку `int atoi(const char *str);` и включите заголовочный файл [`#include <cstdlib>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib). 3) Либо вообще вместо `atoi` используйте [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol): `b = std::stoi(a[0]);`

Comment: Если задумали парсер (или калькулятор арифметических выражений), то не ищите "легких путей". Сканируйте строку по символам и выполняйте все преобразования (в соответствии с грамматикой ваших выражений) сами. В конечном итоге получите более вменяемый код

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вот мой скрипт для преобразования из строки в число

```
inline unsigned int toInteger(string x)
{
    if (key != "")
        return stoi(x);

    return 0;
}
```